# ReactJS Dynamic Children and onClick events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with a ReactJS component using a Mixin and dynamic children firing the onClick event. I have a react component, that based on some props passed to it, will push additional react components into an array. Then in the final return statement from the render method, add these components to the content. These dynamic children define an onClick event in their render method and use a handler from the mixin. However, only the handler on the parent fires. I never get a click event on the children. However, if these children are hardcoded, the onClick handler does indeed fire. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Rough example:

Mixin:

```
var eventhandler = {
    handleClick: function(e) { console.log('click', this.name); }
};
```

The component and its child component:

```
 var foo = React.createClass({
    mixins: [eventhandler],
    name: '',
    ...
    render: function() {
        children_comps = [];
        if(somecondition) {
            children_comps.push(<ChildComponent id={this.props.id} />);
        }

        return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}><p>asdf</p>{children_comps}</div>);
    }
};
```

ChildComponent:

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [eventhandler],
    name: '',
    ...
    render: function() {
        return(<div onClick={this.handleClick}>CHILD {this.props.id} OF THE WILD</div>);
    }
};
```

Comment: Btw foo should be `Foo`. Other than that rest seems to be working fine http://jsbin.com/ginune/22/edit

Comment: That exact same bug has been driving me mad for the last 3 days ! We need help !

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla yes, this works because children are hardcoded. I have an app where i parse some text in a textbox, and display it using a JSON inspector component. Once the user changes the text, the JSON inspector updates, but does not handle clicks anymore...

Comment: @VincentLecrubier That is the exact problem I have. I have still yet to resolve it completely. Luckily it has not been too much of an issue so far, but it's going to show it's head on down the road.

Comment: The code is working for me too. The children are getting click events. I don't fully understand the comment about the children being hard-coded.  Please provide details on the how they are made dynamic.